# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: LDAP: error code 32 -

Tags: java, exception, active-directory, ldap, windows-server

This is my Java Code, I created a domain named: trial.com, in which I created a user named "test1@trial.com".

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.AuthenticationException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;  
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.directory.ModificationItem;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import java.util.Hashtable;


public class Password_ADTesting{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LdapContext ctx = null;
        try{
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();  
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,  "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");  
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");  
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "test1@trial.com");  //"tom@trial.com"
                    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "Panda123*");  //"Panda123*"
                    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/dc=trial,dc=com"); 
            ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null); 
            System.out.println("Connection Successfull");
            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userPassword","Panda23*"));
            ctx.modifyAttributes("CN=Test1,CN=Users,DC=trial,DC=com", mods);
            //"CN=Test1,CN=Users,DC=trial,DC=com"
            System.out.println("Success");
        }catch(AuthenticationException authEx) {
            System.out.println("Active Directory Authentication failed");
            authEx.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Password Cannot be Changed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>java Password_ADTesting
Connection Successfull
Password Cannot be Changed
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310028C, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
        'DC=trial,DC=com'
 ]; remaining name 'CN=Test1,CN=Users,DC=trial,DC=com'
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3284)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3205)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2996)
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1504)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:277)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:192)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:181)
        at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.modifyAttributes(InitialDirContext.java:167)
        at Password_ADTesting.main(Password_ADTesting.java:30)
```

I get authenticated, but not able to change the password. It shows name not found exception. But when I find the distinguished name attribute, it's correct as shown below:

[image]

Could someone help me out with this???

Comment: By the URL you provide to the `InitialContext`, you are already in the subtree `dc=trial,dc=com`, so when you look for `CN=Test1,CN=Users,DC=trial,DC=com` in that subtree you won't find it. I would remove the suffix from the initial URL.